# VMware 5 Player - Ubuntu 14.04 guest autofit - open-vm-tools

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I would like to have an Ubuntu 14.04 guest autofit the VMware Player 5 window. It works with the VMware provided Tools (if you unpack/setup), but VMware recommends using open-vm-tools, as it is fully supported by them. However, the guest is not autofit then. What am I missing?

Using a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to Ubuntu 16 and to Gnome 3 but the solution may work on 14 as well. (Unity support is being dropped apparently.)

I installed (`sudo apt-get install`)

- `open-vm-tools`   and
- `open-vm-tools-desktop` (a separate package!)

Then either of these made autoresize and copy-paste work:

- `vmtoolsd -n vmuser` or
- `vmware-user-suid-wrapper`

Apparently the latter is needed for proper vmblock handling (see [this link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/vmware-user-suid-wrapper.8.html) in the manpages).

I will put the latter in my startup script.